# How to add data to attribute table in ArcGIS 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I have a question about how to add data manually to the attribute table of a shapefile. Whenever I add data to the file or need to change data in the file, I right-click on the layer and select "Edit features". Then I open the attribute table of the file and begin adding/changing data. I save my edits, save the entire file, and then stop editing. The data is saved in the attribute table.
The problem I am having is that the data I add to the attribute table never shows up on my map (I have chosen to add the data to my map as a point -- the points are labeled by the values in a selected column)

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe you are displaying these data using data from a column in the table but the records you are editing have new or different values from those defined in the symbology? If so, try adding values or add all values from symbology.

Comment: It sounds like you may be editing attributes only and not adding any new features. Are you familiar with the Create Features tool?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your replies. @PolyGeo you are correct. I was not adding the data as features first.. i was hoping i could skip that step! Thank you for your help

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question to make it more precise. At the moment I don’t think I have enough detail to write an answer based on my comment.